# Laravel - Database design for a Reservation system

Tags: laravel

I want a database schema that some users (host) come and provide their rooms for some certain date and the users can reserve them so here is how it works.

For example I provide my room from now 3/26/2019 until 3/29/2019 and the user comes and by a datepicker selects a date for example from 3/26/2019 until 3/28/2019 and the user reserve the room.

So I want I did I made a table for my property (room):

```
Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('type');
        $table->text('title');
        $table->float('base_price');
        $table->integer('base_availability');
        $table->integer('max_occupancy');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and here i think i should make a prperty calendar table and make some relation between them thats all i could guess so any idea how to do that ??

Comment: I would create a `reservations` table and link it to `properties` through a belongs to relationship so the reservation has a property_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a 'reservations' migration

```
Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->bigIncrements('id');
 $table->integer('property_id');
 $table->date('start_date');
 $table->date('end_date');
 $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then create relationships between them. In the Property Model

```
public function reservations()
{
 return $this->hasMany(Reservation::class, property_id)
}
```

In the Reservation Model

```
public function property()
{
 return $this->belongsTo(Property::class, property_id)
}
```

Read more about relationships here https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Comment: ok thanks for your answer but how can i make the available dates for reserve so for example a provider of room wants the users just to reserve the room for certain days